# Смысл предложения "Девушкам из высшего общества трудно избежать одиночества"

Tags: смысл

Объясните, пожалуйста, смысл такого предложения:

"Девушкам из высшего общества трудно избежать одиночества".

Сегодня я спорил сразу с десятью коллегами, у двух из которых высшее образование. Они утверждали, что смысл такой:

Девушки из высшего общества никогда не бывают одинокими (так как их всегда окружают молодые люди).

Comment: Достаточно послушать песню, чтобы понять, что речь идет об одиночестве. )))

Comment: Коли вы говорите о споре, то представьте и точку зрения другой стороны.

Comment: Спасибо за ответы! Я их распечатал и покажу сегодня коллегам :-) Я не предоставил свою точку зрения, потому что для меня ответ не менее очевиден, чем для Вас: "Девушки из высшего общества, как правило, остаются одинокими". Я был уверен, что Вы его повторите.

Answer (score 2):

```
Сегодня я спорил сразу с десятью коллегами, у двух из которых ВЫСШЕЕ ОБРАЗОВАНИЕ
```

Ответ настолько очевиден, что возникает встречный вопрос о качестве высшего образования в наше время :)).

Одиночество присутствует в их жизни (или придет в нее рано или поздно), и **трудно** этого **избежать**.

Comment: Простите,  но мне думается, что качество высшего образования - отдельно, а  "качества" пресловутого "высшего" общества - отдельно.

Comment: Да, М_Г, что-то вы тут навертели. "Высшее общество" и "высшее образование" явно не кстати тут в одну кучу свалены.

Comment: @Мимоходов Я отреагировал на фразу "Сегодня я спорил сразу с десятью коллегами, у двух из которых *высшее образование*". Похоже, меня не поняли ни Вы, ни Римма :((

Comment: @М_Г Каюсь,  _не сразу_ поняла Вашу иронию.

Answer (score 1):

"Ты натура утонченная,
Папа твой в посольстве служит дипломатом.
Достоевским увлеченная,
А ведь замуж выходить давно уж надо".

Если у девушки большие запросы, **то у нее велики шансы остаться одинокой** (утонченных принцев не так много, на всех не хватает).

Answer (score 1):

Я уже написал, что "споры о споре" бесполезны, если нет точки зрения противоположной стороны. Но, покопавшись в хитросплетениях формулировки Арины, решил все-таки добавить по существу.

Я очень сомневаюсь, что вы правильно передали позицию сразу десятерых коллег, включая "двух с высшем образованием". Ну не могут они все сразу не понимать,  что "трудно избежать одиночества" имеет смысл прямо противоположный.

Автор (если понимать фразу буквально) утверждает, что ***такая девушка как раз вполне может, чуть ли не должна, остаться одинокой, ибо ИЗБЕЖАТЬ ЭТОГО ТРУДНО.*** Спорить можно только о смысле этого самого **неизбежного одиночества**. Я ограничусь тем, что это сама принадлежность к высшему свету накладывает свои требования на личную жизнь. Видимо, речь идет об одиночестве душевном, что отчасти стыкуется с контекстом. Приходится вертеться в свете, в конечном счете рано выйти замуж, оставаясь в душе непонятой, нереализованной...

Что тут еще добавить, не знаю. Разбирать детально авторскую логику, почему он так сказал, я пока не вижу необходимости, вопрос так и не стоит. *Во всяком случае мне не сильно нравятся объяснения у Arina и М_Г, а Серж в комментариях вообще не раскрывает смысл того, что он хотел сказать, возможно он тоже не понял смысла.*

(++++)
Кстати, если не ограничиваться песенным контекстом, то вот довольно подробно изложенная концепция, почему это так.

http://oldfisher-mk.livejournal.com/151184.html

Я её не комментирую, просто для полноты картины.

Comment: Спасибо! Очень качественный ответ. Но Вы зря сомневаетесь по поводу сразу десятерых человек, включая двух с высшим образованиям. Все они до единого интерпретировали это предложение с точностью до наоборот.